# Ajax call to Express app does not pass data

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, reactjs, express

I am building an app using React and Express. From a React component I am calling an ajax function that targets a certain Express route. However, my route handler does not receive the data passed with the Ajax request.

My Express app (I put the specific route in the main app.js for testing purposes):

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

var lists = require('./routes/lists');

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/lists', lists);

app.get('/lists/show', bodyParser.json(), function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

My Ajax function (reqData is {id: this.props.id} when called):

```
export default function(reqData, path, method, onSuccess, onError, onComplete) {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                if(onSuccess) onSuccess(xhr.responseText != '' ? JSON.parse(xhr.responseText) : '');
            } else {
                if(onError && xhr.responseText != '') {
                    let data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                    if(data.ExceptionMessage) onError(data.ExceptionMessage);
                }
            }
        }
    };
    let url = window.location.href.replace('#', '') + path;
    xhr.open(method, url);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(reqData));
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(reqData));
    return xhr;
}
```

I know that bodyParser is working, because the console.log in the route handler prints {} to the server-side console, indicating that the req.body is empty.

I have tried passing reqData into xhr.send with and without JSON.stringify, neither have worked. But the json prints to the browser console perfectly.

I am completely at a loss as to where my request is going. Do I fundamentally misunderstand how xhr.send and Express routes interact?

Comment: One nitpick: you don't need a second `bodyParser.json()` in `app.get('/lists/show'...`, because you already use it globally in `app.use(bodyParser.json());`. Though I don't expect it to mess things up.

Comment: Haha yes, I didn't have that initially, I added it while debugging to see if it made a difference and forgot to take it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, now I think I know where the issue is - it is the method you use with XHR:

```
xhr.open(method, url);
```

If you use GET, then you won't have a request body. If you use POST, then the handler is somewhere in `./routes/lists`.

Assuming you only do `console.log` in the provided snippet, you actually use GET. According to [Mozilla docs for XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send):

> The XMLHttpRequest.send() method sends the request. [...] send() accepts an
>   optional argument for the request body. If the request method is GET
>   or HEAD, the argument is ignored and request body is set to null.

Comment: Thank you! This definitely seems correct, I will test it when I get home.

So if I want to pass paramaters with the request, if I want to use GET I will have to pass it in the URI? And if I want to use the req.body I'll have to use a POST request? All I want to do is return a database document corresponding to the ID I pass it, so I'm assuming GET would be better?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Semantically, POST is used to create or process something (submit a form, write a post etc.) and GET is used for retrieving. You can use other modules, such as `querystring` or parametrized routes in Express to extract data from URI in GET requests.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to use some kind of ajax library like: https://github.com/yuanyan/react-ajax

Comment: For one, I think my code is perfectly acceptable and I'd like to figure out why it isn't working. In the future I may use one.